# how to set top margin of superview in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode

I have the following code to try to set the bound of my superview

```
let allSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let allWidth = allSize.width
        let allHeight = allSize.height

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:0,y:0 + 34),size: CGSize(width:allWidth,height:allHeight))
```

and this is the result that I got

[image]

what I really want that the red part to be in the top of the screen not on the bottom

Comment: why you are setting the self.view's frame ? its wrong your Viewcontroller's view should be full. You must set the origin and frame of the subview's.

Comment: try setting the origin and frame of your image view and the button.